# Multi Nested Dynamic Routes in Expo Router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I have seen similar posts like this, but all of them with no answer and my guess is that at the moment it is not possible that is why. So I would like to ask directly here whether it is possible or not currently (Expo router v3.4) to multiple nested dynamic routes like the following:

```
/catalogue/[idCatalogue]/product/[idProduct]
```

If someone knows for sure it is not possible, I would appreciate if someone could confirm it in an answer, so we all can stop asking the same question. Or, if it is possible, share the answer.

Thank you very much in advance.

Enrique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is my [solution](https://github.com/lanfr0/test_expo-router) to handle multiple dynamic nested routes in Expo Router (v3). I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).